# Rake import from external database tasks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

The application I'm working on runs import tasks each night to get information from an external database and processes and writes it to the local PostgreSQL database. This is so it can be viewed in our application.

We do the following:

- Create a connection to the external database
- Perform some currency conversion
- Do some calculations on the data based on the average
- Check if the item already exists and update if it's changed
- Also check to see how it is classified and change the category to fit our categorisations
- Create the item if it does not exist

All of this data is on different tables in the external database, so I've created a task for each table (about 30), but I am repeating myself excessively so I'm looking for some guidance on how to DRY this bad boy up.

```
desc 'Imports foo Data'
task :foobar_import => :environment do

# Connect to legacy db

class OldDb < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :cleardb
    self.table_name = 'foobar'
end

class Import < OldDb
    self.table_name = 'foobar'
end

# Currency Conversion

require 'money'
require 'money/bank/google_currency'

# set the seconds after than the current rates are automatically expired
Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.ttl_in_seconds = 86400
# set default bank to instance of GoogleCurrency
bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new

    @gbp = bank.get_rate(:USD, :GBP).to_f
    @eur = bank.get_rate(:USD, :EUR).to_f
    @aud = bank.get_rate(:USD, :AUD).to_f      
    @cad = bank.get_rate(:USD, :CAD).to_f    
    @nzd = bank.get_rate(:USD, :NZD).to_f      

Import.all.find_each do |u|

    # Define Variables

    @price = u.UnitPrice
    @interest = u.UnitSold
    @company = u.Company
    @legacy_id = u.id
    @end_date = u.EndDate
    @category = u.Category

    # Calculate average

    def average_interest(company)
        Dailydeal.where(company: company).average(:interest)
    end

    @company_average = average_interest(u.Company).to_f

    if @company_average == 0
        @company_average = 1
    end

    # Calculate Status

    def average_change_interest
        @average_change_interest = (@interest - @company_average) / @company_average * 100
        @average_change_interest = @average_change_interest
    end    

    # Does item exist?

    if Dailydeal.exists?(:legacy_id => @legacy_id, :company => @company)
    # It exists.
        @historical_interest = Dailydeal.where(:legacy_id => @legacy_id).pluck(:interest)

        # Another statement to check that the Interest != UnitSold

        if @interest != @historical_interest
        Dailydeal.where(:legacy_id => @legacy_id, :company => @company).update_all(:interest => @interest, :end_date => @end_date, :interest_changes => @interest_changes, :status => average_change_interest) 
        end
    else

    # Doesn't exist

    # Set Category            

    case @category
        when 'Apparel'
            @category = 'Apparel & Footwear'

        when 'Gadgets'
            @category = 'Electronics & Accessories'

        when 'Gifts'
            @category = 'Miscellaneous'

        when 'Health & Cosmetics'
            @category = 'Health & Beauty'

        when 'Home'
            @category = 'Home & Furniture'

        when 'Other'
            @category = 'Miscellaneous'

        when 'Toys'
            @category = 'Toys & Kids'

        else

            @category

        end


    # Convert Currencies 

    # GBP

    def gbp_currency_conversion
        @gbp * @price
    end

    # EUR

    def eur_currency_conversion
        @eur * @price
    end
        # AUD

    def aud_currency_conversion
        @aud * @price
    end

        # CAD   

    def cad_currency_conversion
        @cad * @price
    end

        #NZD

    def nzd_currency_conversion
        @nzd * @price
    end

    Product.create(
          :name => u.ProductName,
          :link => u.ProductLink,
          :image_url => u.ImageUrl,
          :price => u.UnitPrice,
          :interest => u.UnitSold,
          :start_date => u.StartDate,
          :end_date => u.EndDate,
          :revenue => u.Revenue,
          :company => u.Company,
          :category => @category,
          :country => u.Country,
          :price_eur => eur_currency_conversion,
          :price_aud => aud_currency_conversion,
          :price_gbp => gbp_currency_conversion,
          :price_cad => cad_currency_conversion,
          :price_nzd => nzd_currency_conversion,
          :status => average_change_interest,
          :legacy_id => u.id)
    end
end

puts "Successfully imported data from foobar"

end
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything excessive.  Are you saying that you have 30 files that look just like this, but access different databases?

Comment: Exactly @Carl, so  I have a script like this for each table I am accessing in this external database